# Sybase insert into temp table with identity column

Tags: sybase-ase15

I'm trying to insert records for couple of columns from a physical table into a temp table with customized IDENTITY. It creates the identity column (field name = idnum), but the values are 0 for all rows. I'm using below code. If anyone can help me what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: I'm trying this is Sybase ASE 15.7**

```
SELECT
  * INTO #achu_test
FROM (SELECT TOP 10
  idnum = IDENTITY(8),
  First_Name,
  Last_Name
FROM Employees) myTable
```

Comment: My bad! I misplaced the IDENTITY. instead of using it before "* INTO", I used inside the Subquery.

    SELECT
            idnum = IDENTITY(8),* INTO #achu_test
    FROM (SELECT TOP 10
      First_Name,
      Last_Name
    FROM Employees) myTable

A good sleep might have given the result for me :)

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question (eg: with the contents of your comment).

Comment: thanks bro, i posted!

Comment: No problem. I found the information useful as I ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

My bad! I misplaced the IDENTITY. instead of using it before "* INTO", I used inside the Subquery.

```
SELECT idnum = IDENTITY(8),* INTO #achu_test 
FROM (SELECT TOP 10 First_Name, Last_Name FROM Employees) myTable
```

A good sleep might have given the result for me :)